# Qual é a finalidade das opções RESTRICT, CASCADE, SET NULL e NO ACTION?

Tags: mysql, sql

Quando vou criar um relacionamento de tipo chave estrangeira entre duas tabelas no MySQL, eu posso especificar algumas opções adicionais nos eventos **ON UPDATE** e **ON DELETE** que estão associados a alteração e exclusão de registros.

As opções são:

1. `RESTRICT`
2. `CASCADE`
3. `SET NULL`
4. `NO ACTION`

Um exemplo prático de ilustração utilizando a opção `NO ACTION`, veja abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuariorelsupermercado` (
    `idUsuario` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `idSupermercado` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `fk_usuario_rel` (`idUsuario`),
    INDEX `fk_supermercado_rel` (`idSupermercado`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_supermercado_rel` FOREIGN KEY (`idSupermercado`) REFERENCES `supermercado` (`idSupermercado`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario_rel` FOREIGN KEY (`idUsuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`idUsuario`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Eu tenho algumas dúvidas a respeito dessas opções.

## Dúvidas

- Qual é a finalidade de cada uma dessas opções?
- No que essas opções influenciam na minha base de dados?

Comment: Esclarecida sua dúvida ? marque como resposta por favor. Obrigado

Comment: Eu costumo marcar depois de dois dias, para dar mais tempo p que outras pessoas respondam :)

Comment: Hmmmmm blz, até estranhei pela sua pontuação, normalmente os novatos que não marcam. Mas blz, boa prática. Vlw

Answer (score 36, accepted):

São opções para as chaves estrangeiras, tentando simplificar ao máximo:

**RESTRICT:** Rejeita a atualização ou exclusão de um registro da tabela pai, se houver registros na tabela filha.

**CASCADE:** Atualiza ou exclui os registros da tabela filha automaticamente, ao atualizar ou excluir um registro da tabela pai.

**SET NULL:** Define como null o valor do campo na tabela filha, ao atualizar ou excluir o registro da tabela pai.

**NO ACTION:** Equivalente ao RESTRICT.

Há ainda o **SET DEFAULT:** Define o valor da coluna na tabela filha, como o valor definido como default para ela, ao excluir ou atualizar um registro na tabela pai.

mais informações: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

***Exemplos:***
Você possui uma tabela de Cidade e um de Cliente, 
Supondo:

```
Cidades:
id|Nome
 1|São Paulo

Cliente:
id|Nome  |Cidade_id
 1|Fulano|1
```

Ao atualizar / excluir o registro da cidade de são paulo:

**RESTRICT/NO ACTION:** o banco irá rejeitar o comando, retornando uma exceção de violação de chave estrangeira.

**CASCADE:** Se alterar o valor da coluna id da Cidade, também será alterado o valor da coluna Cidade_id na tabela de Cliente. Se excluir a cidade São Paulo, também será excluido o Cliente 1, Fulano.

**SET NULL:** O valor da coluna Cidade_Id dos registros que estiverem utilizando o valor 1, São Paulo, serão definidos como null.

*Complementando:* **No que essas opções influenciam na minha base de dados?**

Mantém a integridade dos dados.

Comment: No caso do RESTRICT/NO ACTION ele impede q eu atualize todas as colunas ou só a coluna da chave estrangeira?

Comment: acredito que só da coluna que é referenciada na chave estrangeira